# Cambiar orden de los elementos en nodo de documento XML

Tags: c#, visual-studio, xml

Desarrollo una aplicacion que firma un documento XML..hasta alli perfecto...

Pero debo cambiar el orden en que aparecen estos elementos

```
-<Signature xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="id-e34ffbff277e8d1432e864436aa118824">
```

Deberia aparecer asi:

```
-<Signature Id="id-e34ffbff277e8d1432e864436aa118824" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" >
```

Mi codigo

```
 private XmlDocument FirmaXadesEPES(XmlDocument xmlDoc, X509Certificate2 certificate)
        {

            SignedXml signedXml = new SignedXml(xmlDoc);
            signedXml.Signature.Id = "id-e34ffbff277e8d1432e864436aa118824";
            signedXml.SignedInfo.CanonicalizationMethod = SignedXml.XmlDsigExcC14NTransformUrl;
            signedXml.SignedInfo.SignatureMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmldsig-more#rsa-sha256";

            string URI = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#";
            XmlElement qualifyingPropertiesRoot = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "QualifyingProperties", URI);
            qualifyingPropertiesRoot.SetAttribute("Target", "#SignatureId", URI);

            XmlElement SignedSignatureProperties = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "SignedSignatureProperties", URI);

            XmlElement signaturePropertiesRoot = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "SignedProperties", URI);
            signaturePropertiesRoot.SetAttribute("Id", "SignedPropertiesId", URI);

            XmlElement timestamp = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "SigningTime", URI);
            timestamp.InnerText = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffZ"); //2011-09-05T09:11:24.268Z
            SignedSignatureProperties.AppendChild(timestamp);

            XmlElement SigningCertificate = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "SigningCertificate", URI);
            XmlElement Cert = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "Cert", URI);
            XmlElement CertDigest = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "CertDigest", URI);

            SHA1 cryptoServiceProvider = new SHA1CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] sha1 = cryptoServiceProvider.ComputeHash(certificate.RawData);


            XmlElement DigestMethod = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "DigestMethod", URI);

            DigestMethod.SetAttribute("Algorithm", SignedXml.XmlDsigSHA1Url);
            XmlElement DigestValue = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "DigestValue", URI);
            DigestValue.InnerText = Convert.ToBase64String(sha1);
            CertDigest.AppendChild(DigestMethod);
            CertDigest.AppendChild(DigestValue);
            Cert.AppendChild(CertDigest);

            XmlElement IssuerSerial = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "IssuerSerial", URI);
            XmlElement X509IssuerName = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "X509IssuerName", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
            X509IssuerName.InnerText = certificate.IssuerName.Name;
            XmlElement X509SerialNumber = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "X509SerialNumber", "http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#");
            X509SerialNumber.InnerText = certificate.SerialNumber;
            IssuerSerial.AppendChild(X509IssuerName);
            IssuerSerial.AppendChild(X509SerialNumber);
            Cert.AppendChild(IssuerSerial);

            SigningCertificate.AppendChild(Cert);
            SignedSignatureProperties.AppendChild(SigningCertificate);

            signaturePropertiesRoot.AppendChild(SignedSignatureProperties);
            qualifyingPropertiesRoot.AppendChild(signaturePropertiesRoot);

            // /////////////////////////////////
            XmlElement SignaturePolicyIdentifier = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "SignaturePolicyIdentifier", URI);
            SignedSignatureProperties.AppendChild(SignaturePolicyIdentifier);

            XmlElement SignaturePolicyId = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "SignaturePolicyId", URI);
            SignaturePolicyIdentifier.AppendChild(SignaturePolicyId);

            XmlElement SigPolicyId = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "SigPolicyId", URI);
            SignaturePolicyId.AppendChild(SigPolicyId);

            XmlElement Identifier = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "Identifier", URI);
            Identifier.InnerText = "https://tribunet.hacienda.go.cr/docs/esquemas/2016/v4.1/Resolucion_Comprobantes_Electronicos_DGT-R-48-2016.pdf";
            SigPolicyId.AppendChild(Identifier);

            XmlElement SigPolicyHash = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "SigPolicyHash", URI);
            SignaturePolicyId.AppendChild(SigPolicyHash);

            DigestMethod = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "DigestMethod", URI);
            DigestMethod.SetAttribute("Algorithm", "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256");
            DigestValue = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "DigestValue", URI);
            byte[] shaCertificate = { 0x06, 0xb3, 0x90, 0xb6, 0x45, 0xbb, 0x68, 0x3a, 0xde, 0x72, 0x8e, 0xb8, 0xf9, 0x79, 0x27, 0xd9, 0x18, 0x01, 0x67, 0xdb };
            SHA256 sigPolicyHash = SHA256Managed.Create();
            byte[] sigPolicyHashValue = sigPolicyHash.ComputeHash(shaCertificate);
            DigestValue.InnerText = Convert.ToBase64String(sigPolicyHashValue);
            SigPolicyHash.AppendChild(DigestMethod);
            SigPolicyHash.AppendChild(DigestValue);

            XmlElement SignedDataObjectProperties = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "SignedDataObjectProperties", URI);

            XmlElement DataObjectFormat = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "DataObjectFormat", URI);
            DataObjectFormat.SetAttribute("ObjectReference", "#r-id-1");
            signaturePropertiesRoot.AppendChild(SignedDataObjectProperties);
            SignedDataObjectProperties.AppendChild(DataObjectFormat);
            XmlElement MimeType = xmlDoc.CreateElement("", "MimeType", URI);
            MimeType.InnerText = "application/octet-stream";
            DataObjectFormat.AppendChild(MimeType);
            // ///////////////////////////////////////////////////////////// 
            DataObject dataObject = new DataObject
            {
                Data = qualifyingPropertiesRoot.SelectNodes("."),
            }; 
            signedXml.AddObject(dataObject);
            signedXml.SigningKey = certificate.PrivateKey;
            KeyInfo keyInfo = new KeyInfo();
            KeyInfoX509Data keyInfoX509Data = new KeyInfoX509Data(certificate, X509IncludeOption.ExcludeRoot);
            keyInfo.AddClause(keyInfoX509Data);
            signedXml.KeyInfo = keyInfo;

            //Reference 1
            Reference reference2 = new Reference();
            reference2.Id = "r-id-1";
            //reference2.Type = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties";
            reference2.Type = "";
            reference2.Uri = "";
            XmlDsigXPathTransform XPathTransform = CreateXPathTransform("//. | //@* | //namespace::*", xmlDoc);
            reference2.AddTransform(XPathTransform);
            reference2.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
            reference2.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
            signedXml.AddReference(reference2);

            //Reference 2
            reference2 = new Reference();
            // reference2.Id = "R2";
            reference2.Type = "http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties";
            reference2.Uri = "";

            reference2.DigestMethod = "http://www.w3.org/2001/04/xmlenc#sha256";
            reference2.AddTransform(new XmlDsigExcC14NTransform());
            signedXml.AddReference(reference2);

            signedXml.ComputeSignature();
            XmlElement xmlDigitalSignature = signedXml.GetXml();
            xmlDoc.DocumentElement.AppendChild(xmlDoc.ImportNode(xmlDigitalSignature, true));
            bool checkSign = signedXml.CheckSignature();
            //return xmlDoc.OuterXml;

            return xmlDoc;

        }
```

Comment: En la especificación de XML, el orden de los atributos no tiene importancia, y es usualmente mejor que se considere de esa forma. ¿Alguna razón específica por la que quieres controlar el orden?

Comment: Ok ...sstan  ...Agregala como respuesta para marcarla